# Does a StopIteration exception automatically propagate upward through my iterator?

Tags: python, iterator, termination

I'm implementing an iterator in Python that wraps around another iterator and post-processes that iterator's output before passing it on. Here's a trivial example that takes an iterator that returns strings and prepends `FILTERED BY MYITER:` to each one:

```
class MyIter(object):
    """A filter for an iterator that returns strings."""
    def __init__(self, string_iterator):
        self.inner_iterator = string_iterator
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        return "FILTERED BY MYITER: " + self.inner_iterator.next()
```

When the inner iterator finishes, it will raise a StopIteration exception. Do I need to do anything special to propagate this exception up wo whatever code is using *my* iterator? Or will this happen automatically, resulting in the correct termination of my iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to do anything special - the `StopIteration` exception will be propageted automatically.

In addition - you may want to read about the `yield` keyword - it simplifies creation of generators/iterators a lot.

Comment: Excellent, I just learned that I can use `yield` and generator expressions in the `__iter__` method of a class. I wasn't sure how to use these in an iterable class.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the `StopIteration` exception will be propagated.

Answer (score 1):

What happened when you tried it? :-)

But yes, StopIteration exception are not special and will propagate until something traps them. The next() method does not trap them, and self.inner_iterator.next() will raise a StopIteration when there is nothing left to iterate over.